# How to extract time from datetime module and increment it

Tags: python, file, datetime, counter

I am trying to increment time. For that I stripped time from datetime and tried to add that. But it throws an exception. What is wrong here?

```
st_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(st_time, '%H:%M:%S').time()
en_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(en_time, '%H:%M:%S').time()


while st_time < en_time:
    if str(st_time) in line:
        between = True
        break
    st_time = st_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Exception:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need full datetime objects. Not just time. This is a design constraint to forbid wrapping around of time, guaranteeing that

```
b = a + delta
a == b - delta
```

which would be violated if delta became bigger than 24h.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this part:

```
st_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(st_time, '%H:%M:%S').time()
```

The error says that you can't add a datetime.time type and a timedelta type. Look, if you do:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now().time()
b = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

a+b
```

This will throw an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

But if you, instead, do:

```
import datetime

# Notice there's no .time()
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

a+b
```

It will work.

Comment: I did the changes and now it increments. But after increment I need the time portion only(because the file in which I am searching  contains only h:m:s format ). So I am checking like this: `for str(st_time.time()) in line:` But it is not entering the for loop. It just increments from starting time to ending time

Comment: Have you also changed it in the while loop condition? In your question you have `while st_time < en_time` and now it should be `while st_time.time() < en_time`. And if you also removed the `.time()`from the `en_time` variable it should be `while st_time.time() < en_time.time()`

Comment: Can you provide the data in your file or something? It's hard to know what's happening without seeing your test data. Need a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta                                                                                                                                                                                                     

datetime.combine(date.today(), st_time) + timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: datetime does not have a attribute called 'combine'. And I need to increment by seconds...like 00:00:01, 00:00:02.... 00:01:00...

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`